# gtk+ signal emitted when window/dialog is "presented"

Tags: python, c, gtk

Is there a signal that is emitted when a window/dialog is `presented` in GTK+?

Example: when issuing this command to the GTK widget dialog:

`dialog.present()`

is there a resulting signal?  Or is there any signal that denotes the "showing" of a window/dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `notify::visible` signal will be emitted whenever the visibility state changes, i.e. the window is shown or hidden. The `show` signal isn't documented but from the source it appears that it is an action signal; you can call it yourself using

```
dialog.emit('show')
```

and the widget will show itself, apparently *without* triggering the `notify::visible` signal.

Comment: I found that the signal "visibility-notify-event" serves this purpose too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "show" signal (inherited from Widget) will do this.